# How to get recycle view checked item text in MainActivity?

Tags: android, checkbox, android-recyclerview

Any idea, how to get this check box data on text view which is behind this recycle view. I Inflate custom layout on activity but don't know how to get checked item in text view.
[image: how to get data of checked items]

```
 holder.custom_check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onCheckedChanged: " + holder.textView.getText().toString());
            if (isChecked) {
                selected = selected + holder.textView.getText().toString();
            }

        }
    });
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**Thanks in Advance**

Comment: What type of objects are the checkboxes? Are they standard `CheckBox` widgets?

Comment: One textview and one check box in there

Comment: Are you using any model class to store the texts? If yes, can you post it along with the code?

Comment: simple one activity is there, under that i'm inflating one layout for **recyclerview**

Comment: below part is the recycle view part

Comment: one way i'm using right now is adding items in one string , and removing item from that string, but this is not the good way, i think so